# Requested runtime (Python 3.10.5) is not available for this stack (heroku-20)

Tags: python, heroku

I am trying to deploy my app using Heroku as follows:

```
$ git push heroku master
```

But it says *`Requested runtime (Python 3.10.5) is not available for this stack (heroku-20)`* and I using python 3.10.5 which support all stacks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEusG.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You must use the _exact_ version string given for a [currently supported runtime](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support#supported-runtimes). That means `python-3.10.5` (all lowercase, no spaces, with a hyphen between `python` and the requested version), not `Python 3.10.5`. See the linked duplicates.